# Where to put non-essential .pl files in a distribution?

Tags: perl

I would like to include a few additional .pl files in my CPAN module. These files are not essential to use the module, but are provide useful functionality/glue when the module is used in some common frameworks and applications.

Currently, I just include the .pl files in a "extras" directory of the distribution. This has the drawback that the files are not installed on `make install`. Is there a way to include them in the installation and where should they go? (They aren't executables and don't belong in "bin".) Would "share" make sense? Or are these kinds of files usually just not installed and it is left to the user to get them out of the .tgz archive and use as needed?

I use Dist::Zilla to manage my distribution.

Comment: The one example I can think of that loosely relates to this is [`Mojolicious`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious), which has 3 files in the  [`script directory`](https://metacpan.org/source/SRI/Mojolicious-4.91/script) that are installed with the module: `hypnotoad`, `mojo`, and `morbo`.  However, it also has an example directory with 6 more .pl's that aren't installed.  I think I'd lean toward the middle ground idea of using a `/share` that the user can selectively add to the path, however really depends on the enduser's perceived expectations.  Good question

Comment: @Miller these Mojolicious scripts get installed in "bin", right?

Comment: On my windows box they are installed to `C:\strawberry\perl\site\bin`, so yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I liked @Joe's answer, except that in my case the files were [WebWork macros](http://webwork.maa.org/wiki/Macro_file_template) -- individual .pl files that make my module callable from WebWork end-user's code. So they don't fit under any of the categories discussed here, and as .pl files can't be made a module.

This is what I ended up doing:

1. put all .pl macro files into 'extras/WebWork' in the distribution.
2. add to "dist.ini" file a `[ShareDir]` stanza with `dir = extras` property.
3. now the WebWork admin can install my distribution from CPAN and then use `perl -MFile::ShareDir -e 'print File::ShareDir::dist_dir("Statistics-R-IO")'` to find the macros and make them available in WebWork.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the following:

- If they're actual complete programs or are almost complete, polish then up and make them standalone items that could go into `/bin` with POD of their own.
- If they're utility glue, make a `::Utils` module for them to live in and document their usage.
- If these are useful code snippets but not something you can install somewhere or are sample usages or handy idioms, create a `::Cookbook` all-POD module and include them there with the appropriate illuminating explanation for each one.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly how Dist::Zilla works, but the resulting archive has to be compatible with what ExtUtils::MakeMaker creates.

When you create a module with `module-starter`, it creates a module template using `ExtUtils::MakeMaker`. It creates several files and directories like the `lib` directory where your module lives and the `t` directories where your tests live.

One thing it doesn't create is a `bin` directory. However, if you create a `bin` directory, and you put files under this directory (such as Perl scripts), these files will be installed under the `bin` directory in your Perl's distribution and linked to `/usr/local/bin` or `/usr/bin`. Would this be a good place for your scripts?

Comment: These aren't executables and aren't intended to be used from the command line. That's why I didn't want to put them in `bin`. I'll clarify this in the question.

Comment: So whatfor are they good if they aren't executable? If they are modules they should have the .pm extension and go into the lib directory. If they are example snippets put them in the documentation.